# Mulitple Background Images with the same class

Tags: html, css, background-image

I definitely didn't use the correct title so apologies ahead of time. I simply don't know how to word my question so here goes.

I'm using several Call to Actions on a landing page as full width clickable divs. I'd like to use a different background image for each but I'm having trouble getting this to work. I've done it in the past with different background colours but the same code doesn't seem to work for me. Below is what I have so far. Thanks!

```css
#paralax_cta { width: 100%; margin:0; text-align: center; padding: 50px 0 50px 0; position: relative; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; -moz-transition: all 0.2s; transition: all 0.2s;}
#paralax_cta:hover { opacity:0.9; }
#paralax_cta a { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; text-decoration: none; /* Makes sure the link doesn't get underlined */ z-index: 10; /* raises anchor tag above everything else in div */ background-color: white; /*workaround to make clickable in IE */ opacity: 0; /*workaround to make clickable in IE */ filter: alpha(opacity=0); /*workaround to make clickable in IE */ }

#paralax_cta .bg1 a { background-image: url(../images/cta-backgrounds/office-blurred-red.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center; }

#paralax_cta .bg2 a { background-image: url(../images/cta-backgrounds/office-blurred-blue.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center; }
```

```html
<div id="paralax_cta class="bg1"">
 <h2>CALL TO ACTION</h2>
 <a href="#" title="Call to Action"></a>
</div>

<div id="paralax_cta class="bg2"">
 <h2>CALL TO ACTION</h2>
  <a href="#" title="Call to Action"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS selection for background-image is not correct. It should be

**HTML**

```
<div id="paralax_cta" class="bg1">
 <h2>CALL TO ACTION</h2>
 <a href="#" title="Call to Action"></a>
</div>

<div id="paralax_cta" class="bg2">
 <h2>CALL TO ACTION</h2>
 <a href="#" title="Call to Action"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#paralax_cta.bg1 h2 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x100');
}

#paralax_cta.bg2 h2 {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x100');
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/38dk8p37/)

Answer (score 0):

You should not have two divs with the same id. Change

```
    <div id="paralax_cta class="bg1"">
     <h2>CALL TO ACTION</h2>
        <a href="#" title="Call to Action"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="paralax_cta class="bg2"">
     <h2>CALL

 TO ACTION</h2>
     <a href="#" title="Call to Action"></a>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="paralax_cta" class="bg1"">
 <h2>CALL TO ACTION</h2>
    <a href="#" title="Call to Action"></a>
</div>

<div id="paralax_cta2" class="bg2"">
 <h2>CALL TO ACTION</h2>
     <a href="#" title="Call to Action"></a>
</div>
```

And fix your css selectors as pointed out by Manoj Kumar

```
#paralax_cta.bg1 h2{

}

#paralax_cta2.bg2 h2{

}
```

Comment: Didn't even see that. I changed the ID to a class. All is well. Thanks.